# Horizontal View Swiping with ViewPager like android market

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to print title CATEGORIES,FEATURED,TOP PAID etc. like android market. I am trying this in ViewPager but I did not do it. I put titles in top of layouts but I dont want it.

I want all titles is shown in top,right and left pages' titles shown in top and when I slide the page to right,Page title comes on middle.

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-T0ubrNZd4ro/TlOx2EZGnXI/AAAAAAAAAp0/p7PQWuJc8Ns/s1600/MarketSwipe.png

How can do it using the ViewPager?

Answer (score 2):

In this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686514/how-to-put-a-tabbedlayout-inside-a-viewpager)

Has two links in it;
The first is a link to an explanation of how to achieve it and the second is a link to a library that allows you to do it very easily. It even has a demo apk.