# How to: Put a TabbedLayout inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, tabbed-view

Am trying to achieve something like the image in this [url](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)
I have implemented that behavior with [this](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions)  library

And i have succedded. What i want is to add another horizontally-scrollable layer under the one shown. Imagine an app that has the days of the week as the primary scroller and some specific tv channels in the second scroller; The idea is to allow the user to pick the day and then the channel to check whats on.

This is the best approximation i can give for what i want, but i dont know how to implement the second scroller. Can i do it with tabs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

[ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)